# Modular Architecture for a Large Application With Best Practices and Usage of Storyboards and XIBs

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, model-view-controller

We are a team, creating a very big application for iPad that serves as an eReader for unprivileged children. The app is built halfway and I thought we should take a step backwards and review the whole design of the application. The application we are building should be very, very compliant with the current software development architecture practices for iOS. I have the explanation along with the questions below:

The application right now, has about 50 views (and increasing) and most of the Top-Level views are in the Storyboard (a single storyboard, that is) and the others are in XIBs (for the sub-views, reusable item renderers etc).

Is this approach alright?

Should XIBs be completely omitted for the modern iOS applications?

Should the storyboard be right the way it is or should it be broken down into sub-storyboards? If they should be, how should the exact process of decomposing the storyboard be done? How would the modules be determined?

If you have some tips to manage the application in the right way or some rule of thumbs to assist in a streamlined and modular application, please mention it in your comments.

I'm sorry for the long text up there and I thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a subjective one, but in my opinion it is still valid, and desirable, to use Xibs alongside storyboards. The idea of storyboards is nice, but with the current implementation they are definitely lacking some functionality, the most glaring of which is view reuse. I have worked on a few large projects recently, and storyboards always start out nice, but sooner or later you find yourself copy and pasting table cells, and then controllers, and then you have to change things in multiple places with each update, which is totally unmaintainable. So yes, definitely stick with the Xib files for reusable views.

I am less keen on the idea of multiple storyboards however. While this is easy enough to achieve technically, for me it invalidates the purpose of storyboards entirely. Their only use is as a (relatively) clear overview of the flow of controllers through the application. They add a few small conveniences, but in general I find they often create more code than they save, and create some odd code patterns (eg `prepareForSegue:`, having to temporarily store ivars when you want to segue to a controller in code that needs properties setting). As you say, how do you split up the storyboards into sub-storyboards? I can only think that whatever partitioning scheme you choose would be somewhat arbitrary, and liable to change at a later date when the app structure changes, which would be no fun at all. Maybe if your application has distinct modes of operation it makes sense to split up the storyboard, but I don't think this would apply to most apps.

So, IMO, single storyboard but use Xibs for reusable views.